# Javascript datepicker date defaulting to 01-01-1970 HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datepicker

I am using datepicker is highcharts where I have 2 datepickers.

My problem is that it keeps defaulting to 1970 where I want it to show the current month.
The actually show: 01-01-1970.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {


        $.getJSON('test.json?callback=?', function(data) {


            // Create the chart
            window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1,
                    inputDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y',
                    inputDateParser: function (value) {
                        value = value.split('-');
                        return Date.UTC(
                            parseInt(value[2]),
                            parseInt(value[1]) - 1,
                            parseInt(value[0])
                        );
                    },
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'test'
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {



                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'test',
                    data: data,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                 }}]

            }, function(chart) {

                // apply the date pickers
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
                }, 0)
            });
        });


        // Set the datepicker's date format
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                this.onchange();
                this.onblur();

            }alert(dateText);
        });


    });

</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, datepicker.setDefaults mighthave an option to also set the initial dates. Or just call the inputDateParser method of the rangeSelector of the chart with the dates you want. Your code doesn't contain any reference to the dates you want to use, or is that somewhere in the test.json file?

Comment: No, there are no dates with 1970 in the json file. They are all from 2016

Comment: I mean, I'm not fully familiar with highcharts, which part of this code sets the datetime picker to use the dates in the json? Will using the json file as the data for the chart series also set the dates? Or are you supposed to manually update the datepicker with the correct dates? Because that might be the issue...

Comment: If i understand right, your using data that highcharts has rendered to pass to JQuery's datepicker? If so i would check exactly what the DatePicker is receiving, either with a breakpoint or a `console.log`. Whenever i see a `1970` date it usually points to a failed parsing.

Comment: All the json file contains are the plotting dates: [1464048000000,4],[1464134400000,2]  ... etc ... None of the dates have 1970 on it so I'm supported to set the default date onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have look below code is working fine I have also tested it.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }}]

        }, function(chart) {

            // apply the date pickers
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
            }, 0)
        });
    });


    // Set the datepicker's date format
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            this.onchange();
            this.onblur();
        }
    });

});
</script>

<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks the same as mine?

Comment: Yes this one works ... the only difference seems to be this "filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?" :o/

Comment: I added the ?callback=? and now I'm getting: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

{"1300752000000":11,"1301356800000":4,"1329782400000":22,"1330387200000":2,"

Comment: if possible share here your complete code so that I will check and let you know how you can fix this.

Comment: The code is what I posted...plus my data is [[1423008000000,1],[1423094400000,1],[1425513600000,42],[1425600000000,90],[1425945600000,15],[1426032000000,1],[1426636800000,2],[1427068800000,1]] and I've added ?callback=? to the url end